# Global Javascript Properties - memory usage

Tags: javascript, memory

I'm building various d3.js dashboards which frequently refer to a javascript_properties.js file which includes properties such as:

```
var all_charts = (function() {

   return {
     width:860,
     height:500,
     from_date:"",
     to_date:"",
     highlight_color:"#00FFFF"
   }

}());
```

I use these properties frequently within various functions.

My question is:

Is there any harm in calling each property direct every time I use it or would it be more efficient to declare a local variable at the beginning of each function if a property is going to be called more than once?

To show an example. A local variable:

```
 var width = all_charts.width;
```

OR calling

```
all_charts.width
```

as many times as required during a function.

There may be little discernible difference?

Comment: Make your code readable and don't worry about it, the effect is nonexistent related to the cost of other logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't about memory usage, it's about lookup time.

Yes, caching the property to a local variable may make it faster when using that repeatedly afterward, as the JavaScript engine doesn't have to traverse the scope chain up to the global level to find `all_charts` and then look up `width` on it.

**But**, it's unlikely to make a *noticeable* difference unless you're using these properties hundreds of thousands of times in the same function.

---

Side note: There's no point to the function in the `all_charts` code, what you have does exactly what this does, just more indirectly:

```
var all_charts = {
  width:860,
  height:500,
  from_date:"",
  to_date:"",
  highlight_color:"#00FFFF"
};
```